# Why does an empty array returned from strings.Split have a length of 1 in golang?

Tags: go

I'm just starting out learning golang, and I've encountered something quite strange. When you get an empty array back from a call to strings.Split, it has a length of one.

Example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    test := strings.Split("", ",")

    fmt.Println(test)
    fmt.Println(len(test))
}
```

This outputs:

```
[]
1
```

Why is this? If this is expected behavior, what is the correct way to check if an array is empty?

Thanks

Comment: Because array is not empty. First element of it is an empty string `""`.

Comment: In cases such as this it's very useful to try fmt.Printf with "%#v" format string, as it prints out the exact Go representation of the value. In this case. `fmt.Printf("%#v\n",test)` prints `[]string{""}`, which makes it obvious that the slice is not empty, but contains an empty string.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember that for future use.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I dont understand why it the length will be 2. can you please explain. I have printed the length. it shows length ONE.

Comment: And why does it return an empty string? Shouldn't it just be an empty array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As said in the comments by @u_mulder, the array isn't empty as it contains an empty string.